# Bootstrap navbar justify-content tag not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need to space my links out across my bootstrap navbar. I have written code for this but I can't seem to figure out why/where it keeps getting overridden.

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

```css
.navbar {
  background-image: url("images/navbarbgnew.png");
  background-size: cover;
  margin: -30px 0 15px 0;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Helvetica," sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light mb-3">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          BOOKS
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Branding Sutra</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          LEARNING LAB
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Workshops</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Classes</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Audio Downloads</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using native Bootstrap classes whenever possible because using custom css for things of this nature tends to cause unexpected results that would require even more custom css to fix.

To get the desired effect, you first need to add the `justify-content-around` class to the parent div and then put each of the main navigation items into their own `ul` element as shown in the code snippet below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light mb-3">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-around" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    BOOKS
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Branding Sutra</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    LEARNING LAB
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Workshops</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Classes</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Audio Downloads</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: thank you for this- it's the right direction but I'm trying to get the links to space out across the entire navbar, not just be centered. and the padding around them would adjust based on the size of the screen, if that makes sense